# Using jQuery to position one element next to another no matter the value

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

this is a wonderful website.  I am a new programmer who is having trouble trying to figure out how to position one element next to another no matter what the prior element is.

For Example, 
If I have element A that can have a value of anything
And if I have element B which looks like the word "Dog".

I want to place Dog right after element A.

So if element A is Cat: I want it to show "Cat Dog"
And if element A is Hippopotamus: I want it to show "Hippopotamus Dog"

The reason I say this is because I am having spacing issues.  It is my understanding this can be accomplished with jQuery.

Here is an example css:

```
Element A {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
}
Element B {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Thank you for reading.
Note: Neither element is a child of another or anything like that.  They are completely random elements.  Also the code has to be sensitive to browser resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method will move an element after another element.

```
$("Element A").after($("Element B"));
```

Browser resizing is irrelevant. If an element is after another element, it will be there regardless of the size.

Comment: Thank you so much for that.  It was in front of my face the whole time but you pointed it out for me.  Thanks again!